# C# SaveFileDialog doesn't create a file and won't close

Tags: c#, xml, listbox, savefiledialog

I'll start by noting that I'm a complete beginner to C# and I've been trying to "learn by doing."

The overall project is a media player that I'm creating and augmenting from a couple of YouTube videos I've been watching. I'm at a point where I'd like to understand the SaveFileDialog and how to save items from a ListBox into an xml file.

Before I can get there, however, I'm having trouble with just getting the SaveFileDialog to save anything at all and then close.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "XML-File | *.xml";
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Playlist";
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) ;
        }
```

Right now, when I click the "Save" button (btn_save), the Save dialog will open and it will default to an xml file, but no file will save after clicking Save, and then after clicking Save, the dialog just opens again and again until I select Cancel.

If I try to add
`SaveFileDialog.Close();`
I get an error saying "SaveFileDialog" does not contain a definition for 'Close', but I figure I've got to set *something* that tells the dialog to close after hitting Save.

What will help me most here is the "fix" for this and then some comments in the code that explain what's occurring on each line so that I perform more relevant searches and read further.

That said, any help with this would be appreciated. Please let me know if I need to include additional code in this example.

Comment: Get rid of the line "saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();"

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this code would show the savedialog more than twice...

Comment: The saveFileDialog just returns a name of a file and does not create the file.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's have I would expect code that writes "hello world" to a text file to look like:

```
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text file | *.txt";
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Playlist";
    
    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) 
      return;

    File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, "hello world");
}
```

You can tweak it for XML etc, but the key concepts are:

- Show the dialog with `ShowDialog()` - your code will pause at that point while the dialog is open and resume when it closes
- Inspect the result and if it's not OK (i.e. the user clicked Cancel), `return` without doing anything
- Otherwise, do something (like writing a file)

Comment: This is giving an error saying "The name 'File' does not exist in the current context". Does "File" need to be defined somewhere?

Comment: It's the `System.IO.File` class. You need a `using System.IO;` at the top of your code file. You can point to the red wiggly line, and a button with a lightbulb appears (it is also in the margin) - in the lighbulb menu it will offer to fix it for you - click the top option and it will add the `using` statement to the top of your code

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you!. Would you have any recommendations on what to read to set up the saved file to take the text from the ListBox?

Comment: ListBoxes don't have text, per se.. they have items which are (or, can be) represented as text. If you want to take the contents of a listbox and write to a file, I'd recommend you use a stringbuilder to build up the text, and enumerate the listbox's items collection, processing each item in turn. It could be as simple as `var sb = new StringBuilder(); foreach(var o in listbox.Items) sb.AppendLine(o); File.WriteAllText(somepath, sb.ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to save the file with the information obtained from the SaveFileDialog component.

Maybe this could be helpful to you:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Stream myStream ;
  SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
  saveFileDialog1.Filter = "XML-File | *.xml";
  saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Playlist";
  saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

  if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
  {
    if((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
    {
      // Code to write the stream goes here.
      myStream.Close();
    }
  } //end if ShowDialog
} //end Click Button
```